# How to stop mesh cutting through another mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, constraints

I want to fold a plain mesh with two folds. The first fold is good, but when I make the second fold the edge of the first fold cuts through the mesh next to it. I have added print-screen of the problem I am having.
Is there a way to stop the mesh cutting through (maybe a constraint)?
What is the best way to deal with these sorts of problems?
[image]

Comment: you can't, you need to control this with your bones, also maybe change the geometry, for example use 2 edges to create a fold and not one unique

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking 2 edge fold might be the solution.